# Getting permission error when trying to attach .apk file of an app using gmail

Tags: android, uri

I am trying to share an app's apk using Intent.

It is sharable using all apps except gmail. When trying to attach apk file using gmail, it's saying permission denied.
 Which permission i should set and where? Please check view.setOnClickListener.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != applicationInfo) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(applicationInfo.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));

        }

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
               File srcFile = new File(appsList.get(position).publicSourceDir);
                Intent share = new Intent();
                share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(srcFile));

                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Sharing"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: gmail does not allow sending android applications as attachments hence "permission denied".
Upload it to google drive instead and share it from there.

Comment: Myappsharer use to send it using gmail too. Question is how ?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you discuss your app development plans with qualified legal counsel. What you are doing may represent copyright infringement, and it will be important for you to understand the criminal and civil penalties that you may be subject to.

Comment: Keep in mind that sending an APK is generally a very bad idea - with the ability to provide [multiple apks](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html), there is absolutely no guarantee that the same APK will work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

The `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is a dangerous permission that must be [requested at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on API 23+ devices. Gmail does not request this permission and therefore has no permission to read any `file://` URIs you send it.

You should instead use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) per the [Sharing Files training](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) and the [Sharing Content blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#ad2c). `FileProvider` sends a content URI which allows the receiving app to read the file without any additional permissions.

Comment: `publicSourceDir` on `ApplicationInfo` should not be pointing to external storage AFAIK. Similarly, `FileProvider` will not work here, as `FileProvider` cannot be taught this specific location, though some other `ContentProvider` could.

Comment: @CommonsWare - yes, you'd need to copy the file to to your cache/files/external files directories if you want to directly use `FileProvider` (which is probably still easier than writing your own ContentProvider to do this).